# How to send data of a 3d camera connected with one ros computer into second ros computer to compute the data in second computer?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot running ros in raspberry pi so it's computational power is low. I need to send the 3d camera data connected to rasperry pi  of robot into my laptop via wifi to compute the data and form a 3d map. I'm using kinect 360 as the 3d camera and kinetic distriution of ros.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346718/how-to-send-data-of-a-3d-camera-connected-with-one-ros-computer-into-second-ros-computer-to-compute-the-data-in-second-computer?/) by [Manish12344321](https://answers.ros.org/users/52512/manish12344321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to do this by the ROS networking [instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup).

You just need them on the same network and setup the ROS master URI so that they can create the important connections.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0